# align button and dropdown in a same line bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align a button and a select drop down in a same line.

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="pull-right margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated cart-class"
id="cart-classlatest-arrival1">Add To Cart<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</button>

<select class="form-control pull-left margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated custom-class">
    <option> 750 Gms </option>
</select>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spys5bex/3/) for the same.

Comment: remove `form-control` css class from `select`

Comment: I made width as `auto` and it works well for me..

Answer (score 1):

Remove css class `form-control` under the select tag.
Update the button tag and replace class `pull-right` with `pull-left`.

For responsiveness add this:

```
 @media (max-width: 320px) {
   button[type="submit"],
   select {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

See: [jsfiddlle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/edden87/khmvkeqo/1/)

Edit: Added responsiveness support.
Note: Please only paste relevant CSS and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add css -

```
.form-control{width: auto;}
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/spys5bex/4/

Comment: It doesn't remain responsive with this, for `max-width: 766px`, It becomes like [this](http://i.imgur.com/i9OLOP9.png)

Comment: You can add media css for that and make them 100% width. @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
 #cart-classlatest-arrival1,
 .form-control{width: 100%;}
}

Comment: it's working fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/spys5bex/8/

Comment: may be because these are some of the extra css being applied.

check [this](http://pastebin.com/huFHBd4G)

Comment: Try to add media css at end of css file. May be that is issue as it's working on jsfiddle.

Comment: See my answer @Suraj.

Answer (score 0):

you have .form-control with width set to 100% in your css. remove that and add width attribute to button and option menu seperately.